# Is there any way to order more than 30 items in a single order in the management interface for Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Having a Manager noble assigned allows you to create jobs, which obviously saves time in finding the appropriate workshop.

However, there appears to be a maximum of thirty items in a single "job/order", is there any way around this? Aside from the obvious of just ordering multiple times?

Comment: UPDATE: this restriction no longer exists in recent versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:** As of a recent update (0.43.04) the hard limit of 30 items has been removed entirely.

Currently, no -- the 30 unit maximum seems to have been hardcoded, fairly arbitrarily.

As to why, you'd probably have to ask on the Bay 12 forums -- Toady is generally pretty good at communicating with his players.

Comment: As a corollary I seem to recall a binary patch for this floating around; but I don't know if it's up to date, or exists for any platform but windows.

Comment: UPDATE: this restriction no longer exists in recent versions.